# Too many entity_writes when creating multiple entities in cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am noticing a weird(?) behavior when I am creating a large number of entities (about 1000) in my datastore.

I have a REST method which creates 1000 entities of same kind. I am using

```
datastore.put(entityObject);
```

to create entities. When I check the trace timeline I see this:

[image: details for main rest call]

If I check details of every subsequent put call it shows this:
[image]

And there are a ton of these put calls! Even the 'Insights' tab says: 
[image]

Here is my entity class:

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;
import com.sm.task.entity.Task;

@Entity(name = "TMS.Task")
public class TaskEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String title;
    private String description;

    @Index
    private String status;


    public Task toTask() {
        return new Task(
                id,
                title,
                description,                
                status);
    }

    public Key<TaskEntity> key() {
        return Key.create(TaskEntity.class, id);
    }

    public static Key<TaskEntity> keyFor(String id) {
        return Key.create(TaskEntity.class, id);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

I didn't find any setting which causes or controls this behavior. Can anyone please help me understand the reason of this issue and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Can you share your code that puts the entities? It looks like you are putting individual entities 1000 times, instead of doing one batch put of 1000 entities.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making 1,000 `put`calls to store 1,000 entities, you should make 2 `put` calls with 500 entities in each (just pass a list of entities to be saved). This is way faster and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @tx802 for pointing out my stupid mistake! I was making 1000 calls each putting 1 entity. After your answers, I made change to create a list of 1000 entities and put them in one shot. Now I am seeing another interesting observation. entity_writes are doing a batch of 10 entities at a time.     (Can't put a screenshot here but this is the detail for every call: ) /datastore_v3.Put
Details

Property                                  Value
gae/datastore/count                 10
gae/datastore/entity_writes 10
gae/datastore/index_writes 110
gae/datastore/size                 10

Comment: Here is my code which does actual creation:  `public void createTasks(List<Task> tasks){
        ArrayList<Entity> taskEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Task t : tasks) {
            Entity taskEntity = createTaskEntity();
            taskEntities.add(copyToTaskEntity(taskEntity, t));
        }
        datastore.put(taskEntities);
    }`

Comment: With python api you can specify the batch size. May be look for that in the java api.